# Strange warning using listings with hyperref and naturalnames=true

Tags: hyperref, listings

I stumbled across the following strange behaviour. Every time that I include a `lstlisting` block I get a warning:

```
destination with the same identifier (name{lstnumber.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,onecolumn,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x, latin1]{inputenc} %unix-windows-compatible
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true
, hyperfigures
, bookmarksnumbered
, naturalnames
, plainpages=false
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \begin{lstlisting}[label=l1,caption=c1]
      listing1
      dsfkdsj
      fdsf
      fsdf
 \end{lstlisting}
 \begin{lstlisting}[label=l2, caption=c2]
      listing2
      sdfkdsf
 \end{lstlisting}
 \begin{lstlisting}[label=l2, caption=c2]
      listing2
      sdfkdsf
      sdff
      dsff
 \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The resulting warnings are:

```
/mwe_latex/mwe.aux: LaTeX Warning: Label `l2' multiply defined.
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: destination with the same identifier (name{lstnumber.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: destination with the same identifier  (name{lstnumber.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: destination with the same identifier  (name{lstnumber.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: destination with the same identifier  (name{lstnumber.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: destination with the same identifier  (name{lstnumber.3}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: destination with the same identifier  (name{lstnumber.4}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
/mwe_latex/mwe.tex: LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

It seems that the warnings correspond to the number of lines. Also I could set `naturalnames` to `false` and the warnings would be gone. But I don't know what the implications are.

Comment: Well, do you really need `naturalnames`? Remove that. And  you have the label `l2` twice... Usually the link anchor names should be computed by `hyperref`, not LaTeX itself.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I was going to ask the exact same question...

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8x, latin1]{inputenc} %unix-windows-compatible`  is your file utf8 or latin1? it can not be both. I would use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` unless you have good reason not to do that.

Comment: @Mico: Ok, I was faster then ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You usually are...

Answer (score 3):

If `naturalnames` is not set, `hyperref` uses the more sophisticated `\theH...` counter formater approach to set link names, i.e. `chapter.1` etc.

With `naturalnames` it uses `\the....` counter formater, which is `lstnumber`, i.e the listing line number. Now for mere coincidence, the number of lines in the first listing is 4, in the 3rd one it is again 4, so `hyperref` sets an anchor named `lstnumber.4` twice, which is bad of course concerning the link target.

This does not happen with `naturalnames=false` (or removing this option), it uses `\theHlstnumber` which basically defaults to `\thelstlsting.\thelstnumber`, i.e. it couples the line number to the relevant listing and can't occur twice unless the `lstlisting` counter is reset somewhere later on.

In doubt you should not need to use `naturalnames` in `99.9%` of all cases (I never needed it yet).

It is possible to check the anchor name the `hyperref` 'internal' macro `\HyperGlobalCurrentHref`, see the example code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,onecolumn,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[
pdfpagelabels=true
, hyperfigures
, bookmarksnumbered
%, naturalnames % Remove the % in front of naturalnames to see the different output. 
, plainpages=false
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[label=l1,caption=c1]
      listing1
      dsfkdsj
      fdsf
      fsdf
 \end{lstlisting}

 Current \HyperGlobalCurrentHref
 \begin{lstlisting}[label=l2, caption=c2]
      listing2
      sdfkdsf
 \end{lstlisting}


 Current \HyperGlobalCurrentHref
 \begin{lstlisting}[label=l3, caption=c3]
   listing2
   sdfkdsf
   sdff
   dsff
 \end{lstlisting}
 Current \HyperGlobalCurrentHref

\end{document}
```

[image]